# Is there a way to create different d3 axis for unique groups in the data? (d3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create multiarray **joy plot** for some data, but I struggle to make a proper axis. I am facing the problem that each column in the joy plot needs its specific scale domain because the data is different from the other columns.

[image]

The way I have coded the plot is to group the data with d3.groups() and then build the structure of the joy plot with this approach. However, using this approach, I can create the plot but not draw the axis. Is there a way to accomplish this?

My first thought was that I could pass the data (mapped to .data()) to .call(). In the function that .call() calls, I could include some code that creates the scale and axis for each array in the joy plot. However, this doesn`t seem to work because the function that .call calls doesn`t have access to the data.

Here are some example data and the plot that generates the plot:

```
const width = window.innerWidth * 0.9;
const height = window.innerHeight * 0.9;
const margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 20,
};
const groups = 2;
const padding = 10;
const paddingZ = 200;

const gWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
const gHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const histogramHeight = (padding + gHeight + padding) / groups;
const histogramWidth = (padding + gWidth + padding) / groups;
const histogramZheight = (paddingZ + histogramHeight + paddingZ) / 3;

const svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("width", width);

const g = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

const main = async () => {

  data = [
    {bib: 1, split: 1, course: "A", performance: 2.4},
    {bib: 1, split: 1, course: "B", performance: 7},
    {bib: 1, split: 2, course: "A", performance: 2.7},
    {bib: 1, split: 2, course: "B", performance: 8},
    {bib: 2, split: 1, course: "A", performance: 2.9},
    {bib: 2, split: 1, course: "B", performance: 5.0},
    {bib: 2, split: 2, course: "A", performance: 9},
    {bib: 2, split: 2, course: "B", performance: 6},
    {bib: 2, split: 2, course: "A", performance: 3},
    {bib: 1, split: 2, course: "A", performance: 3},
    {bib: 1, split: 2, course: "B", performance: 1.2},
    {bib: 2, split: 1, course: "B", performance: 3},

  ]


  const dataGrouped = d3.groups(
    data,
    (d) => d.day,
    (d) => d.split,
    (d) => d.course
  );

  const cellX = g
    .selectAll(".cell")
    .data(dataGrouped)
    .join("g")
    .attr("class", "cellX")
    .attr("transform", (d) => console.log(d))
    .attr(
      "transform",
      (d, i) => `translate(0, ${i * (padding + histogramHeight + padding)})`
    );

  const cellY = cellX
    .selectAll(".cellX")
    .data((d) => d[1])
    .join("g")
    .attr("class", "cellXY")
    .attr(
      "transform",
      (d, i) => `translate(${i * (padding + histogramWidth + padding)},0)` //${ i * (padding + histogramWidth + padding)},0)`
    );

  const cellZ = cellY
    .selectAll(".cellXY")
    .data((d) => d[1])
    .join("g")
    .attr("class", "cellZ")
    .attr(
      "transform",
      (d, i) => `translate(0, ${i <= 2 ? i * paddingZ : i * (paddingZ)})` //(0, ${i * (paddingZ + histogramZheight + paddingZ)})`
    );

  const path = cellZ
    .selectAll(".lo")
    .data((d) => d)
    .join("path")
    .attr("d", (d) => {
      const xScale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain([-3, 40])
        .range([0, histogramWidth]);

      console.log(xScale.domain());

      const bingenerator = d3
        .bin()
        .domain(xScale.domain())
        .value((d) => d.performance);

      const binnedData = bingenerator(d);

      const topHistogramYscale = d3
        .scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(binnedData, (d) => d.length))
        .range([histogramZheight, 0]);

      const xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(xScale);

      const topHistogramLineGenerator = d3
        .area()
        .x((d) => xScale(d.x0))
        .y0(histogramZheight)
        .y1((d) => topHistogramYscale(d.length))
        .curve(d3.curveBasis);

      return topHistogramLineGenerator(binnedData);
    })


}

main();
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'each column in the joy plot' ? Do you have an example of a joy plot that has the axes you are looking for ?

Comment: https://cmagelssen.no/ - In this rather complex plot you can see that the different subplots (columns) have a different axis. I used a different approach to create that figure